# SSRS: Horizontal alignment on a group

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016

On my dataset I select information from four different years sorted by date and how many subscriptions I had on said date, which looks something like this:

```
Date        Year    Subs    Day
15/09/2014  2015    57      1
16/09/2014  2015    18      2
17/09/2014  2015    16      3
14/09/2015  2016    10      1
15/09/2015  2016    45      2
16/09/2015  2016    28      3
12/09/2016  2017    32      1
13/09/2016  2017    11      2
14/09/2016  2017    68      3
24/08/2017  2018    23      1
25/08/2017  2018    53      2
26/08/2017  2018    13      3
```

What I'm trying to do is create an 'Year' Column Group to align them horizontally, but when I do that, this is the result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP2Xu.png)

Expected result:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4n17.png)

Is this achievable in SSRS? I've tried removing the group =(Details), which gives me the desired result, except it only returns one line of information.

Any insight aprreciated.

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to create a reproducible example so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Details group causes you to get one row per row in the dataset. In your case, I would suggest grouping the Rows by the Day column and create a column group by Year.

First, create the two groups and add columns inside the column group.
[image]

Then, add a row outside and above the Day row group. Place the headings here and then delete the top row. It should look like this:
[image]

Now these 4 columns will repeat to the right for each year and you will get rows based on the number of days in your dataset.