# SSRS column group instances will not align horizontally

Tags: reporting-services

My question is similar to [SSRS: Horizontal alignment on a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890213/ssrs-horizontal-alignment-on-a-group), however I still am unable to display the required result.  I have a tabular report in which I need some columns to expand horizontally rather than vertically.  It seems this is possible by using a column group.  However as shown in my screenshots, I cannot seem to get the data represented by each group instances to line up.  They seem to be offset by the height of the group.  Is there any way to fix this?

I have tried manipulating the properties based on what was posted in the referenced link on SO

Here is a screenshot of my designer:[image]

Here is the problematic output:
[image]

And lastly, here is my desired result.
[image]

Comment: I believe you'll need to Group By `MAT` on your detail line and get the MAX(Fields!MAT.Value) to eliminate the NULLS.

Comment: @HannoverFist  - thank you that seemed to be the ticket.  More specifically for anyone else who runs into this issue  #1:   In Row Groups,  right click (table1_Details_Group) > Group Properties > General > Group Expressions > Add > specify [mat]   #2: in the tablix designer inside the PHSec grouping, update the [mat] expression to =Max(Fields!mat.Value)

Comment: @HannoverFist I'm relatively inexperienced with SSRS as you may have guessed - do you know of any resource that more fully documents SSRS grouping behavior?  Seems it's a simple fix if you know the paradigm.  I didn't run across much in the way of documentation that would have helped me figure this particular problem out.

Comment: I checked but I can't find anything about this "feature" either. It seems that the detail wants a separate row for each record and doesn't aggregate them with the column grouping as you would expect. Very unintuitive.